# Exporting .blend files using OgreXML

Tags: blender

My question is a simple one this time: how can I export .blend files using OgreXML in ubuntu 12.04(x64)? I've installed blender-ogrexml, but how do I get it to work, or am I doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After much searching I found a forum, that lead me to a forum, etc... And I eventually found [this](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=61485) download for linux, windows, and mac, not just windows or mac, Installed it in blender, and it works like a charm.